# java.io.FileNotFoundException file path open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: android

This is my code i am trying to download file in local storage but

```
 private String downloadFile(String MY_URL) {
            int count;
    
            try {
                URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
                int lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(), 8192);
                fileName = MY_URL.substring(MY_URL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, MY_URL.length());
                File outputFile = new File(directory, fileName);
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    
                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
    
                long total = 0;
    
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
    
                    int status = (int) ((total * 100) / lengthOfFile);
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
    
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Connectivity Manager
    
                            //speedTV.setText(downSpeed+" mbps");
                            // speedTV.setText(finalRate);
                            progress_circular_id.setProgress(status);
                            textview_progress_status_id.setText(String.valueOf(status) + "%");
    
                            if (status == 100) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
    
    
                }
    
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
                return "Downloaded at: " + directory.getPath() + fileName;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Abhan", "Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        hideProgressDialog();
    
                    }
                });
            }
            hideProgressDialog();
            return "Downloading Error";
        }
```

i am trying to download file using image URL to my android device sd card
/storage/emulated/0/Movies/RoveDashCam/Photos/2022_0103_124619_001.JPG
but when i a run code i am getting below exception
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Movies/RoveDashCam/Photos/2022_0103_124619_001.JPG: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)r

i am trying to give permission dynamically  but it show permission already granted then also i am unable to download file

please help me what mistake i am doing .

Comment: This error is simply telling you that you don't have storage permission

Comment: i  have given run time  if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) is this permission you are talking  or some other permission ?

Comment: by the way, You are getting errors while reading data here also Android 11+ devices have to handle with SAF(Storage Access Framework) pattern

Comment: yes i am using android 11 + ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION is this permission required?

Comment: Yes, You need that for sure. Also, be careful with this permission. If you planning to upload the app to the play store then you need a strong reason for this permission. because as far as I know, you can do this without permission from SAF.

Comment: can you provide google link where i can find such example because when i try to allow permission then it show disable mode of runtime permission

Comment: @gulabpatel this is solved but when i try to download file i am getting java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream

Answer (score 1):

Every app on Android 11+ can create files in subdirectories of public Movies directoty like in /storage/emulated/0/Movies/RoveDashCam/Photos.

But it should be a movie file.

So change 2022_0103_124619_001.JPG to 2022_0103_124619_001.mp4.

Comment: But i have image file i want to download image file

Comment: Google does not want you to place pictures in a directory for movies you should understand.

Comment: ok thanks for helping is that reason java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream issue is coming?